# "before" vs "before that"

Tags: difference, relative-pronouns

> (Sir Edward) Coke further noted that legal disputes about such matters as inheritance of goods:
>
> > are not to be decided by natural reason but by the artificial reason and judgment of law, **which** law is an art which requires long study and experience, before **that** a man can attain to the cognisance of it: that the law was the golden metwand and measure to try the causes of the subjects; and which protected his majesty in safety and peace. . . .
>
> In other words, neither a king nor any judge can simply decide idiosyncratically what is ‘fair’.
> He must instead apply the existing law.

I know that this was written in 1607, but what's the meaning of **that**? Is it optional? Why or why not?

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74357/why-does-legal-english-sometimes-repeat-the-antecedent-noun-after-which) answers the question of: How would you determine the purpose of which? It doesn't sound like the modern relative pronoun; "which is an art which" sounds curious. This refers to Why does legal English sometimes repeat the antecedent noun after "which"?.

Source: P13, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper

Answer (score 1):

It was common in ME and EModE to introduce a clause serving as the object of a preposition with the complementizer *that*. This use dropped away in ModE.

You may find examples in [*OED I*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt209murruoft#page/252/mode/2up), s.v. **That** *conj.*, definition **I.1.c.**. It's toward the bottom of the final column of the second page at the link.